# Cancel a .Net WebSocket SendAsync Immediately

Tags: .net, websocket, task-parallel-library, asyncsocket, cancellationtokensource

I am using websocket to send out message to 1000 clients. I want to cancel the websocket.SendAsync if the message was not sent out within 100 ms. My code is below.

```
var cancelTaskToken = transport.GetTaskCancelToken();
        cancelTaskToken.CancelAfter(100);
        var webSocket = transport.GetWebSocket().WebSocket;



        var webSocketContext = new WebSocketSendContext(webSocket, message.Value, transport, Counters, _trace);
        var context = (WebSocketSendContext)webSocketContext;
        try
        {
            if (context.socket.State != System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open) return;
            await context.socket.SendAsync(context.payload, System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, cancelTaskToken.Token);
            context.transport.MarkHeatBeat();
            context.counters.MessagesSentToClientTotal.Increment();
            context.counters.MessagesSentToClientPerSec.Increment();

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            context.trace.Error(ex, "cancel socket sending on {connectionId}. websocket state: {webSocketState}", transport.ConnectionId, webSocket.State);
            context.counters.ErrorsTransportPerSec.Increment();
            context.counters.ErrorsTransportTotal.Increment();
            context.counters.ErrorsAllPerSec.Increment();
            context.counters.ErrorsAllTotal.Increment();
        }
```

But in my test, the sendAsync always cacel after 1000 ms. I don't know why websocket doesn't pick up my 100ms setting?

I use serilog/seq to trace my application. Here are the trace image
[image]

Comment: Your log times are indicating that it takes 1000ms between logging events. It is not giving you the actual time it took to cancel the message. It is possible that there is 900ms of compute time both before the  SendAsync() method is called and after the error is logged. Try logging a message immediately before calling SendAsync to see if the time discrepancy is shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SeanOB, you are right. The 1 sec gap in the log is the serilog logging internal. It is not then canceling timeout setting in my CancelToken.

I now can confirm that the cancel did happen after 100ms.